# Can’t find my tests with GitLab CI in kotlin

Tags: maven, kotlin, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

why gitlab-ci can't find my tests? locally in IntelliJ IDEA my tests works, but when i push into repo, gitlab-ci cant find my tests

Maybe the problem is that he can not find the directory of my tests? tests in:
project\src\test\kotlin\group\common\UObject\UObjectTest.kt

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-group</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>project</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.50</kotlin.version>
        <kotlin.code.style>official</kotlin.code.style>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin/group/common</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.0-M1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.2.0-M1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>ktlint</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <configuration>
                            <target name="ktlint">
                                <java taskname="ktlint" dir="${basedir}" fork="true" failonerror="true"
                                    classname="com.pinterest.ktlint.Main" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath">
                                    <arg value="src/**/*.kt"/>
                                    <arg value="--reporter=plain"/>
                                    <arg value="--reporter=checkstyle,output=${project.build.directory}/ktlint.xml"/>
                                </java>
                            </target>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals><goal>run</goal></goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.pinterest</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ktlint</artifactId>
                            <version>0.34.2</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>testCompile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

i modified `<testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin/group/common</testSourceDirectory>` but it still not works, i tried to use **/**/*Test.* instead of **/*Test.* but it also doesn`t work, I think also problem could be in dependencies but i dont know them right, hope anyone could help me.

gitlab-ci just in case

```
image: maven:latest

stages:
  - build
  - ktlint
  - test

variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s settings.xml --batch-mode"

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS compile

ktlint:
  stage: ktlint
  script:
    - mvn antrun:run@ktlint 

test unit:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
```

results

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  40.340 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-03T05:56:03Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What happens when you execute `mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test`on commandline at the root of the project locally? My guess is the classpath isn't set up properly, or it may be being executed at the root/outside the root of your project in the build. you may need to execute `mvn test src/test` or alike to tell it where to find the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, GitLab CI, can't find the tests when you have placed them at a directory level that is not correct. Also, make sure that what you have in your **pom.xml** matches the actual directory hierarchy. In this case,

```
<testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin/group/common</testSourceDirectory>
```

Another example, from the Java world,

```
         <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
```